# Keeping original list item names when using lapply over an existing list

Tags: r, lapply

I have three data frames stored in a list as follows:

```
dat <- list("grp_1" = data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)),
            "grp_2" = data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)),
            "grp_3" = data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)))
```

If the data frame is named "grp_1" or "grp_2", I filter it to keep only the first 10 rows, otherwise, I filter it to keep the first 20 rows.

```
dat_new <- lapply(names(dat), function(x) {
  if(x %in% c("grp_1", "grp_2")) {
    dat[[x]] <- dat[[x]] %>% 
      slice(1:10)
  } else {
    dat[[x]] <- dat[[x]] %>% 
      slice(1:20)
  }
})
```

My function executes properly, but for some reason, I am losing the list element names in doing so (i.e. the output is a list of three unnamed data frames, rather than three data frames named "grp_1", "grp_2", and "grp_3").

Can someone show me how to modify the code above so that the shortened data frames retain their original names?

Comment: One way with `setNames`: `n <- names(dat); dat_new <- lapply(setNames(n, n), function(x) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the names:

```
names(dat)
# [1] "grp_1" "grp_2" "grp_3"
names(dat_new)
# NULL
names(dat_new) <- names(dat)
names(dat_new)
# [1] "grp_1" "grp_2" "grp_3"
```